# Regex multi- AND/OR single-line match using a string beginning and optional ending

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Here's a tricky one, I haven't found any clear indication of whether this is even possible; *matching everything (inclusive) from a starting point indication to the end of the line (single line match) unless there is an ending point indication before another starting point, in which case match everything up to and including it (multi line match)*

Lets say we have the $str =

```
blah blah begin 12345
bleh bleh
begin test
```

We can easily match and for example remove `begin 12345` using `preg_replace('@begin(.*?)@i', "", $str);`, giving us the result:

```
blah blah 
bleh bleh
```

And if we instead have $str =

```
blah blah begin 12345
bleh finish bleh begin test
```

We can also easily remove everything between `begin` and `finish` inclusive using `preg_replace('@begin(.*?)finish@is', "", $str);`, giving us the result `blah blah  bleh begin test`

Using the `s` option this way we can easily match *either* an entire line, or multiple lines. But how should we match *single-line if `finish` isn't found until another `begin`, otherwise multi-line including both the `begin` and `finish`*?

So, for example, if you have the $str:

```
1 begin 2
3 begin 4
5 finish 6
7 finish 8
9 begin 10
```

How would you use a single preg_replace() to remove something like `begin(.*?)(finish)?` for the following expected output?

```
1 
3  6
7 finish 8
9
```

Note that `3` remains because the first "`begin`-and-beyond" match was non-greedy, yet `5` was removed because `finish` came before another `begin`. But `7 finish` remains because it had no `begin`ning. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is entirely possible, but a bit tricky - you can use the following regex to achieve this: `begin(?s)((?!finish|begin).)*finish|begin(?-s).*`.

Let's take a look into the regex. It uses an alternation, where the first alternative matches all the occasions, where `begin` meets a closing `finish`, using a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) and an inline singleline modifier. The second alternative matches the remaining `begin`s and removes the singleline mode.

- `begin` - matches the string `begin`
- `(?s)` - turn singleline mode on
- `((?!finish|begin).)*` - match any amount of characters, that are not starting either `begin` or `finish`
- `finish` - match the string `finish`
- `|` - starts an alternation
- `begin` - matches the sting `begin` (thus all `begin`s that haven't been matched yet)
- `(?-s)` - turn singleline mode off
- `.*` - match the reminder of the line

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rmn1Rw/1)

Tempered greedy tokens aren't very effective, as the lookahead has to be checked for every single character, but we can entroll this to become more efficient. As the enrolled version uses negated character classes and no more dot-matching in the first alternation, we can drop inline modifiers too.

```
begin(?:[^bf]*(?:(?:b(?!egin)|f(?!inish))[^bf]*)*)finish|begin.*
```

- `[^bf]*` - match any amount of characters, that are neither `b` nor `f`
- `(?:b(?!egin)|f(?!inish))[^bf]*+)*` - match `b` or `f` that are not part of the unwanted words, followed by other non `bf`-characters - repeated zero or more times.
- there is a possesive modifier `*+` inside to avoid unnecessary backtracking into the pattern for the non-matching cases.

Another [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rmn1Rw/2)

Comment: As far as my testing shows so far, this works perfectly! Excellent explanation too! Thank you so much!! I noticed you commented on my post in an unbelievable less than 10 minutes with `begin((?!finish|begin).)+finish|begin(?-s).*` though, which also seems to work for the example in my post, what's the difference between the two?

Comment: The pattern from my comment didn't include the inline-singleline modifier (so you had to set it from outside) and the tempered greedy token needed at least one character between begin and finish (`+` instead of `*`)

Comment: Aha... so then what about `preg_replace('@begin((?!finish|begin).)*finish|begin(?-s).*@is', "", $str);` compared to `preg_replace('@begin(?s)((?!finish|begin).)*finish|begin(?-s).*@is', "", $str);`, are they the same or is there any other difference?

Comment: They work the same way, yes - the second one might be a tad slower due to the inline modifier, you also only need `@...@i` for the second one.

Comment: Ahh, nice! Thanks, I hope seeing this helps broaden other peoples perspective over regex use as much as it has mine ^^ however... this is causing mysterious xampp v3.2.1 apache server crashes for me, with no hint of a any related error beyond "client denied by server configuration" on a default configuration, any idea why that might be? Is there anything unusual about this regex that might not work on all platforms? The only thing out of the ordinary I see is `(?-s)`, could that be the culprit?

Comment: No, no idea. I am actually not familiar with php at all :)